# Counting null and missing values using RODBC package

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am working to create a a matrix of missingness for a SQL database consisting of 5 tables and nearly 10 years of data.  I have established ODBC connectivity and am using the RODBC package in R as my working environment.  I am trying to write a function that will output a count of rows for each year for each table, a count and percent of null values (values not present) in a given year for a given table, and a count and percent of missing (questions skipped/not answered) values for a given table.  I have written the code below, trying to get it to work on one variable then turning it into a function once it works. However, when I run this code, the count for total, missing and null values are all the same and the percent of course is 1.  I am not getting any error messages.  I am not sure where the issue lies and it is important to distinguish between missing and null for this project.  Any insight is much appreciated.

test1 <- sqlQuery(channel, "

```
SELECT [event_year] AS 'YEAR', 
       Count(*)     AS 'TOTAL', 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN mother_education_trendable = 'NA' THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END)   AS 'NULL_VAL', 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN mother_education_trendable = -1 THEN 1 
               ELSE 0 
             END)   AS 'MISS_VAL' 
FROM   [GA_CMH].[dbo].[births] 
GROUP  BY [event_year] 
ORDER  BY [event_year]
```

")

test1$nullpct<-with(test1, NULL_VAL/TOTAL)

test1$misspct<-with(test1, MISS_VAL/TOTAL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `CASE` statement inside the `Count` aggregate will populate either `1` or `0` both will be considered in `Count` aggregate so you are getting same count as total.

Zero is a value that will be counted in `Count` aggregate so remove the `ELSE` part in `CASE` statement by default `NULL` will be populated non matching conditions which will not be counted/considered in `COUNT` aggregate

```
SELECT [event_year] AS 'YEAR', 
       Count(*)     AS 'TOTAL', 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN mother_education_trendable = 'NA' THEN 1 
             END)   AS 'NULL_VAL', 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN mother_education_trendable = -1 THEN 1 
             END)   AS 'MISS_VAL' 
FROM   [GA_CMH].[dbo].[births] 
GROUP  BY [event_year] 
ORDER  BY [event_year]
```

Or use `SUM` aggregate instead of `COUNT`

```
SELECT [event_year] AS 'YEAR', 
       Count(*)     AS 'TOTAL', 
       SUM(CASE 
               WHEN mother_education_trendable = 'NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0
             END)   AS 'NULL_VAL', 
       SUM(CASE 
               WHEN mother_education_trendable = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0
             END)   AS 'MISS_VAL' 
FROM   [GA_CMH].[dbo].[births] 
GROUP  BY [event_year] 
ORDER  BY [event_year]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. I decided to use the sum aggregate, however now I am getting an error message when trying to create the percentage variables:

Comment: test1 <- sqlQuery(channel, "select 
                  [EVENT_YEAR] AS 'YEAR', 
                  COUNT(*) AS 'TOTAL',
                  SUM(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = 'NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NULL_VAL',
                  SUM(CASE WHEN MOTHER_EDUCATION_TRENDABLE = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'MISS_VAL'
                  
                  from [GA_CMH].[dbo].[BIRTHS]
                  
                  GROUP BY [EVENT_YEAR]
                  ORDER BY [EVENT_YEAR]")

test1$nullpct<-with(test1, NULL_VAL/TOTAL)
test1$misspct<-with(test1, MISS_VAL/TOTAL)

Comment: I get: Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character. But I have tried to ensure the proper environment is indicated and am unsure how to rectify this. I have tried putting the variables being used in the expression in quotations, however I encounter the same error messages